# shell script expression evaluation into a variable

Tags: bash, shell, git-bash

The below expression

```
var=$(git log --since='$start_date' --until='$end_date' --author='$commit_author' | grep -i 'merge request\|pull request'  | wc -l)
echo $var
```

prints var as zero

but if I echo the above expression

```
git log --since='2018-04-1' --until='2018-06-30' --author='so.sila@xes.com' | grep -i 'merge request\|pull request'  | wc -l
```

and copy it and execute via terminal works

why is that var not storing the value and returns zero

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is that `'$start_date'`, `'$end_date'` etc do not expand to their values as they are in single quotes. Try changing it to double quotes and you may have some luck.